# Gnucash: Checking acct -> Checking acct -> expense account

Tags: gnucash

im new to gnucash but I have most of my accounts working and reconciled now. 
This one however I can't square in the books:

I have gotten a refund on paypal and I transfered the money back to my checkings account. 
The transaction shows up a few days later as a deposit on my checkings account and the transfer field says "assets: paypal" as it should. So far so good.

Now I want to book the deposited refund in my checkings account as a negative expense into an expense account.

However I cant change the transfer field because it would disconnect the link between PP and the checking acct. I also cant split the transaction because its a deposit in the checkings acct and would also be a deposit into the expense acct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The balancing entry to the expense account is the entry in your Paypal account, not either of the entries in the transfer from Paypal to Checking.